# Doctrine 2: Understand how entities works with doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 3 Entities: Person, Affiliation and PersonAffiliation.

In my form, I will display each affiliation as a checked checkbox.

Nowm when the user uncecks the checkbox and click submit, this affiliation should be removed from the  PersonAffiliation table.

The problem is that when I submit without unchecking, my data are duplicated.
Example: aff1 and aff2. When both checked and submit, I will then get aff1 aff1 aff2 aff2.
The same, If I uncheck aff2, I will then have aff1 aff1.

The error is probably somewhere in using the doctrine:

Here is how I am managing that:

- Entity Persom

  ```
  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonAffiliation", mappedBy="person", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
  protected $affiliations;
  ```
- Entity Affiliation:

  ```
  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonAffiliation", mappedBy="affiliation")
  protected $person_affiliations;
  ```
- Entity PersonAffiliation

  ```
  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="affiliations")
  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  protected $person;


  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Affiliation", inversedBy="person_affiliations")
  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="affiliation_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  protected $affiliation;
  ```

An idea on how to resolve that?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Cotroller part:

```
foreach( $enquiry->getAffiliations() as $aff )
    {
    $pAff   = new PersonAffiliation();
    $pAff->setPersonId( $person->getId() );
    $pAff->setAffiliationId( $aff->getAffiliation()->getId() );
    $pAff->setPerson( $person );
    $pAff->setAffiliation( $aff->getAffiliation() );
    $em->persist($pAff);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Form Part:

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{

    $person = $this->person;
    $user   = $this->user;

    $builder->add('firstname', 'text');
    $builder->add('middlename', 'text', array('required'=>false));
    $builder->add('lastname', 'text');
    $builder->add('sex', 'choice', array( 'choices'   => array('m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female'),
                                          'required'  => true, 
                                          'multiple'  => false,
                                          'expanded'  => true));
    $builder->add('email', 'text', array('required'=>false));

    if( $this->addAffiliations ) {
        $builder->add('affiliations', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Athor\'s affiliations',
            'class' => 'SciForumVersion2Bundle:PersonAffiliation',
            'query_builder' => function($em) use ($person, $user){
            return $em->createQueryBuilder('pa')
                ->where('pa.person_id = :pid')
                ->setParameter('pid', $person->getId());
        },
            'property'    => 'affiliation',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your controller and form code.

Comment: I will do it immediately, thans.

Comment: When is that for loop called and where is the checkbox form part?

Comment: @Squazic, here is the entire controler part for my question: http://pastebin.com/SBJgXpF0 The checkbox form part is $builder->add('affiliations' ...

Comment: @Squazic, I edited my questino with the entire buildForm

Comment: You keep mentioning a checkbox, but I don't see it. Also, check your remove statement if you're getting duplicate data.

Comment: Does this `PersonAffiliation` contain only foreign keys? If so, you can melt that down to `ManyToMany` without need for extra entity. Besides, `orhpanRemoval` concept works great with this kind of relation...

Comment: @Squazic, Yes, I have checkboxes when adding "$builder->add('affiliations',...", you can se that "'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true,", that means that this will be checkboxes. How to check remove statement? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @jperovic, (Hvala na pomoci). In which concerns the PersonAffiliation, the table in the database does not contains foreign keys, but there is a possibility to put those fields (only 2 + his id) to be foreign keys (except the id). In which concerns the entity, you can see it here: http://pastebin.com/aC1HNKGs. When to your advice of using manyToMany, should $I use many to many in the PersonAffiliation entity? I will try to take a look on orphanRemoval, I never worked with, I am pretty new in symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Person entity :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Affiliation", inversedBy="people")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="PersonAffiliation")
*/
protected $affiliations;
```

And in the Affiliation entity :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Person", mappedBy="affiliations")
*/
protected $people;
```

Comment: Thank you, and in the PersonAffiliation, how should be the relations with the person and the affiliation? ManyToOne, OneToMany ...

Comment: The PersonAffiliation entity is useless and you must remove it. The table PersonAffiliation with foreigns keys is auto-generated by this line : `* @ORM\JoinTable(name="PersonAffiliation")`

Comment: Thanks, I deleted this entity. However, now I am getting this error  "Fatal error: Method Proxies\SciForumVersion2BundleEntityAffiliationProxy::__toString() must not throw an exception in /home/milos/workspace/conference2.0/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/IdentityTranslator.php on line 62"

Comment: I got that when I try to add in the PersonAffiliation in the controller. If I delete this line, I am getting: "A new entity was found through the relationship 'SciForum\Version2Bundle\Entity\Person#affiliations' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: SciForum\Version2Bundle\Entity\PersonAffiliation@0000000070e64441000000005b6984b7. Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading persist operations on the relationship. If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'SciForum\Version2Bundle\Entity\Affiliation#__toString()' to get a clue."

Comment: Can you write the content of the line 62.

Comment: The first error is comming because I was trying to insert a new Affiliation n the PersonAffiliation Entity, which does not exists I think. Should I leave this portion of code or delete? When I delete, I am getting the second error (See my previous comment)

Comment: The `PersonAffiliation` entity does not exist. You must only use `Person` or `Affiliation` entities. First, you have to declare that protected `$affiliations` and `$people` are `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;`. Then, you create a `$affiliation = new Affiliation()` and then you set $person->addAffiliation($affiliation). [Documentation ManyToMany et ArrayCollection doctrine2](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#initializing-collections)

Comment: Thank you, this is done, but near my Affiliations label in the form, I have: " Fatal error: Method Proxies\SciForumVersion2BundleEntityAffiliationProxy::__toString() must not throw an exception in /home/milos/workspace/conference2.0/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/IdentityTranslator.php on line 62 "

Comment: Maybe in your Affiliation and Person entities, define the __toString methods. I'm not sure.

Comment: Hm, I have allready a __toString method in the Affiliation entity, but apparently this methods results an exception.

Comment: `public function __toString()
    {
     return $this->affiliation;
    }` The affiliation is the name of the affiliation, it is a text

Comment: $this->affiliation is a string ?!

Comment: Yes, the affiliation is defined as: `@ORM\Column(type="text") protected $affiliation;`

Answer (score 0):

You made a `$em->flush()` on each iteration of the foreach. It should be done after the end of foreach isnt'it ?

Moreover, you may use a `ManyToMany` relation.

Comment: Thank you vor your reply jeremieca, i mooved the $em->flush() outside the for loop. Now, in which conecrns the ManyToMany releation, where should i use it, in the Personaffiliation entity? Thanks

Comment: In fact, maybe your Person and Affiliation entities are enough. If you should use `ManyToMany` relation between Person and Affiliation entities.

Comment: You think that I should simply ignore the PersonAffiliation entit and use ManyToMany reletion in the Person and in the Affiliation entity?

Comment: Could you please edit your answer with more details, how should I use the ManyToMany relation (regarding my example). I tryed it before but without success.